# MediatR: INotification handler is being called multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, mediatr

I'm using MediatR 9.0.0 (with MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 9.0.0). I have event notification handler like that:

```
public class StatusChangedEventHandler : INotificationHandler<StatusChangedEvent>
{
    
   public StatusChangedEventHandler ()
   {
   }
    
   public async Task Handle(StatusChangedEvent evnt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      //some code 
   }
}
```

The event is being published from another command handler:

```
public class ChangeStatusCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<ChangeStatusCommand, bool>
    {
        ...
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public ChangeStatusCommandHandler(...,IMediator mediator)
        {
            ...
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Handle(ChangeStatusCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            ...

            await _mediator.Publish(new StatusChangedEvent(int id, string message));

            ...
            
        }
    }
```

The problem is StatusChangedEventHandler.Handle method is being called multiple times - I noticed it seems to be relative to number of command handlers registered in Startup.cs, e.g.

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandA));
```

=> the handler would be called once

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandA));
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandB));
```

=> the handler would be called twice

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandA));
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandB));
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandC));
```

=> the handler would be called 3 time etc.

How to fix that to make handler being called just once?

Comment: Can you show how you're publishing the event?

Comment: Added event publishing code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A call to `services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandA))` doesn't only register that single command handler `CommandA`, it registers all command handlers that are present in the assembly containing `CommandA`; the full assembly is being scanned  for its handlers.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)

> Scans assemblies and adds handlers, preprocessors, and postprocessors
> implementations to the container. To use, with an IServiceCollection
> instance:

You must not explicitly call `AdMediatR` upon the other command handlers;
remove the ones below.

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandB));
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CommandC));
```

Comment: Awesome! Have no idea why I didn't face the issue before, but anyways you saved my day, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to register all commands at once

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YouClass)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add related assemblies only once (without potential duplicates), try the following

```
var list = new List<System.Reflection.Assembly>();
list.Add(typeof(CommandB).Assembly);
list.Add(typeof(CommandC).Assembly);

services.AddMediatR(list.Distinct().ToArray());
```